# How can I add rows to a linked chart on the iCloud (web) version of Numbers?

Tags: icloud, numbers

After creating a spreadsheet based on a budget example with a table and donut chart, I am unable to have new rows appear on the chart.

On the macOS version, an "Edit Data References" button appears upon selection, but this button does not appear on the web version.

Does the web version support this, and if so, where is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Edit Data References" option for a chart is not available in Numbers for iCloud. If you want to add a series of data to an existing chart in Numbers for iCloud, you need to add a new column (or row) within the range of columns (or rows) already included in the chart. See "[Edit chart data in Numbers for iCloud](https://support.apple.com/guide/numbers-icloud/edit-chart-data-gilda8ef2996/icloud)" for more details.

Comment: This is acceptable as the info about the feature not being available in the web version is what I needed. Thank you